# Compare 2 sheets in 2 csv and replace value from one to the other

Tags: excel, csv

I'm trying to compare two sheets in excel and if matching "A" value then copy the value in the "B" to the other "I".

Ex:

Compare

Sheet 1 column A to Sheet 2 column A, if the Alpha numbers match then copy the value in Sheet 1 colum B into Sheet 2 colum I.

I have reference number in both A in need to replace the old image url by the new image url.

I have over 15 000 items and I will have to do this everyday so any automation would be great.

I have 2 csv files.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: post code snippet you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

In Sheet2 column I using formular:

=IF(A1=Sheet1!A1,Sheet1!B1,"Value_if_not_match")

Hope this can help